# How to turn an xml upside down?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a big and complex tree of objects (entities in c#, which I serialize).

For example... A big family tree (parents to children). Family tree of a huge family with a lot of properties for each person. Most of "ends" have some habbits, like skating, video games, fishing, dancing (most kids have only one hobby, some have several hobbies, and some have non). Like this:

```xml
<family>
    <parent>
        <name>Alex</name>
        <age>72</age>
        <sex>male</sex>
        <children>
            <kid>
                <name>Loren</name>
                <age>male</age>
                <sex>45</sex>
                <children>
                    <kid>
                        <name>Mile</name>
                        <age>14</age>
                        <sex>male</sex>
                        <hobbies>
                            <hobby>
                                <name>Bike</name>
                            </hobby>
                            <hobby>
                                <name>Video games</name>
                            </hobby>
                            <hobby>
                                <name>Reading</name>
                            </hobby>
                        </hobbies>
                    </kid>
                </children>
            </kid>
        </children>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <name>Nataly</name>
        <age>67</age>
        <sex>female</sex>
        <children>
            <kid>
                <name>Jordan</name>
                <age>35</age>
                <sex>male</sex>
                <hobbies>
                    <hobby>
                        <name>Skate</name>
                    </hobby>
                    <hobby>
                        <name>Read</name>
                    </hobby>
                </hobbies>
            </kid>
        </children>
    </parent>
</family>
```

Something like this, but a bit more complex, and much larger.

What I need to do, is to turn this tree upside down to make a graph and to run some analysis. The root node needs to be `hobbies`, and the end of the branch has to be a "parent". Like this (not finished):

```xml
<hobbies>
    <hobby>
        <name>TV</name>
        <users>
            <user>
                <name>Melisa</name>
                <age>18</age>
                <sex>female</sex>
                <parents>
                    <parent>        
                        <name>Loren</name>
                        <age>male</age>
                        <sex>45</sex>
                        <parents>
                            <parent>        
                                <name>Alex</name>
                                <age>male</age>
                                <sex>72</sex>
                            </parent>
                            <parent>        
                                <name>Nataly</name>
                                <age>female</age>
                                <sex>67</sex>
                            </parent>
                        </parents>
                    </parent>
                    <parent>
                        <name>Ben</name>
                        <age>male</age>
                        <sex>47</sex>
                        <parents>
                            <parent>        
                                <name>Guy</name>
                                <age>male</age>
                                <sex>56</sex>
                            </parent>
                        </parents>
                    </parent>
                </parents>
            </user>
            <user>
                <name>Mike</name>
                <age>14</age>
                <sex>male</sex>
                <parents>
                    <parent>        
                        <name>Loren</name>
                        <age>male</age>
                        <sex>45</sex>
                        <parents>
                            <parent>        
                                <name>Nataly</name>
                                <age>female</age>
                                <sex>67</sex>
                            </parent>
                        </parents>
                    </parent>       
                </parents>
            </user>
        </users>
    </hobby>
    <hobby>
        <name>Fashion</name>
        <users>
            <user>
                <name>Melisa</name>
                <age>18</age>
                <sex>female</sex>
                <parents>
                    <parent>        
                        <name>Loren</name>
                        <age>male</age>
                        <sex>45</sex>
                        <parents>
                            <parent>        
                                <name>Alex</name>
                                <age>male</age>
                                <sex>72</sex>
                            </parent>
                            <parent>        
                                <name>Nataly</name>
                                <age>female</age>
                                <sex>67</sex>
                            </parent>
                        </parents>
                    </parent>

                </parents>
            </user>
        </users>
    </hobby>
    <hobby>
        <name>Fishing</name>
        <users>
            <user>
                <name>Mathew</name>
                <age>52</age>
                <sex>male</sex>
            </user>
            <user>
                <name>Mike</name>
                <age>14</age>
                <sex>male</sex>
                <parents>
                    <parent>        
                        <name>Loren</name>
                        <age>male</age>
                        <sex>45</sex>
                        <parents>
                            <parent>        
                                <name>Nataly</name>
                                <age>female</age>
                                <sex>67</sex>
                            </parent>
                        </parents>
                    </parent>       
                </parents>
            </user>
        </users>
    </hobby>
...
</hobbies>
```

Does anyone knows, how I can reach the goal?

Hope, that I'm clear enough, and that this isn't repost :)

Comment: I think this would become significantly easier if you made it into a relational database first. I'm guessing, for example, you want all decendants who have a hobby of "TV" for example. You may also be able to use XPath selectors to do what you are asking, but I don't see a real need to physically transform the XML to something else.

Comment: DB is a good idea. I thought of it too, but the requirement is the requirement... I can't deal with DB. Those XMLs are the result of the  serialization of tree of objects. Each tree is build after a scan prossess, which happens on demand. I can't do a lot on those machines and there are many reasons for this. So the DB is not a solution. But thanx :)

Answer (score 3):

Hierarchic inversion is known in the XSLT world as "grouping", and it can be done very conveniently using the xsl:for-each-group construct in XSLT 2.0. Without working through all the logic in your example, it will be something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <hobbies>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//hobby" group-by="name">
      <hobby>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></name>
        <users>
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <user>
             <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::kid/(name, age, sex)"/>
```

etc

Comment: Thank you for the advise! Checking it :)